# Как сделать свой поддомен на github?

Tags: домен, поддомены, git, github

Насколько я знаю там сейчас можно только свой `username.github.com` или же какой-то другой свой поддомен `mysubdomain.github.io`, только вот как их сделать не пойму?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В справке по GitHub есть статья с подробным руководством: «[Creating Pages with the automatic generator](//web.archive.org/web/20160421082401/https://help.github.com/articles/creating-pages-with-the-automatic-generator/)».

Comment: Спасибо что ткнули носом. Я просто лазил везде и не мог найти почему-то.